# Lookups based on criteria across sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, pivot, vlookup, google-query-language

I am trying to extrapolate data from a from response in forms/google sheets.

On the attachment, students can select 1, 2 or 3 in any of the columns. I then need the header of the 3 selections to be looked up on the second sheet in the correct column (reducing it down to everything just in the square bracket is a bonus).

This is an example, in the real thing there'd be more students in the list.

Thanks

[Lookup Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13qoYfIo0JvLso1IG7cgFlObb-4NVg92jcZjQzti37GE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: add more details with example of desired result and the reason. so far your dataset contains high amount of unknowns

Comment: @player0 I have edited the data set. to represent what I want the formula to do. I haven't been able to have an attempt!

Comment: see your sheet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF('Form responses 1'!C2:1000<>"", 'Form responses 1'!C2:1000&"×"&
 REGEXEXTRACT('Form responses 1'!C1:1, "\[(.*)\]")&"×"&'Form responses 1'!B2:B1000, )), "×"), 
 "select Col3,max(Col2) where Col3 is not null group by Col3 pivot Col1"), {2,3,4}, 0)))
```

[image]